# Clique symbol in Math

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I am working with the font Palatino on the [memoir class](http:// ).

```
\uspackage{mathpazo}
```

How can I get the second `C` below in a mathematical formula? (the second `C` refers to the notion of a clique on a graph). As context, it's often used in the statical machine learning literature.

[image]

Comment: `\mathcal{C}`, if I remember correctly. :)

Comment: Or `\mathscr{C}`, in some packages.  See e.g. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: @doncherry I think this question is more about fonts, not looking up symbols.

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Not really, the `mathpazo` package doesn't change the font of the symbol in question. If you compile `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{mathpazo}\pagestyle{empty}\begin{document}$\mathcal{C}$\end{document}`, the only font used will be `cmsy`, which is Computer Modern Math Symbols. Plus you can find that very `\mathcal{C}` on Detexify, which is mentioned in that other question's top answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As zeroth mentioned in a comment, `\mathcal{C}` is probably what you're looking for.

The following document compiles without errors or warnings, and ends up looking like your picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\[ \prod_{C \in \mathcal{C}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're still looking for other "script" fonts, [this article](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Courses/typesetting-script.pdf) suggests `\mathscr{C}`, from either the `euscript` package or the `mathrsfs` package.